# XSLT Current node, axis, dot, self etc. What are they?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am not sure I understand the "axis".

"An axis defines a node-set relative to the current node." (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp). And `self` selects the current node. The "." also selects the current node.

`self` *axis* Contains the context node itself. The self axis can be abbreviated with a single period (.). The expressions `self::*` and . are equivalent. (http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xslt/ch03_02.htm)

So, therefore `//*` selects all nodes, and `//*[self::td]` limits it to `td` nodes below the current node in the tree. This sounds like the same thing as `.//td`. But it isn't.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Not this</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span>
                 <a>This is the title we want</a> 
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><span class="c2">not this.</span></p>
    <p><span class="c2">not this</span></p>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="235"><span class="c2">not this.</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
      <td class="c5"><span class="c4">not this</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So if I run this XSLT,

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:element name="chapter">
        <xsl:element name="title">
            <xsl:value-of select="( //*[self::td])[1]" /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Then I get:

```
<chapter>
    <title>This is the title we want</title>
</chapter>
```

But if we run:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:element name="chapter">
        <xsl:element name="title">
             <xsl:value-of select=".//td[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Then we get:

```
<chapter>
    <title>This is the title we want not this. not this not this not this not this not this</title>
</chapter>
```

That is strange. I would have thought these two were supposed to be equivalent.

`<xsl:value-of select=".//p[1]"/>` returns the value of every p element.

`<xsl:value-of select="( //*[self::p])[1]" />` returns the content of only the very first p element.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, these two are **not** equivalent:

```
.//p
```

selects every `p` that is a descendant of the current node.

```
//p
```

selects every `p` that is a descendant of the root node - i.e. every `p` in the entire document.

---

Next, this:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//td[1]"/>
```

selects all descendant `td` elements that are the first `td` child **of their parent** (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).

OTOH, this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="( //*[self::td])[1]" />
```

selects the first of all `td` elements in the entire document. And it could be written more simply as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//td)[1]" />
```

Comment: So `select="//td[1]"` selects each td element that is the first td of its parent in the whole document, and `select="(//td)[1]"` select the very first td in the whole document.

Comment: @rawtext Yes.  Are you observing a different result?

Comment: No, I am observing what you say. Just slowly understanding thanks. Extra plus for (//td)[1]